# How to create a function that takes dictionary inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argument-unpacking

I am using a module for a project, I have to pass a function to the module and the model does something like:

```py
class module:
   def __init__(self, function, dictionary):
       # dictionary is {'x':2, 'y':4, 'z':23}
       function(**dictionary)
```

And my function is something like:

```py
def function(*foo):
    return sum(foo)
```

The problem is that, the module needs named variables, and will pass it to the function like an unpacked dictionary, and the number of elements in `dictionary` can be variable, so I cannot pre-write the function as `def function(x,y,z): return sum(x,y,z)`, and this raises an error. I do not wish to modify the module, because then, the code will not be universal. How can I solve this problem by just changing my code?

**EDIT:** I need `foo` as a list to use in the function

Comment: The first argument of `__init__` is always `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You module that you can't change is calling your function with:

```
function(**dictionary)
```

You won't be able to write your function to the argument is a list — it's not being passed a list. You can accept the keywords as a dict and the easily make a list. Your  function just needs to be prepared to be called that way:

```
def f(**foo):
```

This leads to:

```
class module:
    def __init__(self, function, dictionary):
       # dictionary is {'x':2, 'y':4, 'z':23}
       function(**dictionary)

def f(**foo):
    print(sum(foo.values()))

module(f, {'x':2, 'y':4, 'z':23})

# prints 29 as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the sum of the values:

```
   def __init__(self, function, dictionary):
       # dictionary is {'x':2, 'y':4, 'z':23}
       function(dictionary.values())
```

The `dictionary.values()` will give a list of `[2, 4, 23]` for your example.

Comment: I don't think you have understood, I **cannot** edit the module

Comment: So, you cannot change `module`, can you change `function`?

Comment: Yes, I can change `function`

Comment: Then see solution from Mark Myer

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(*args,**Kwargs):
    try:
        return sum(*args)
    else:
        return sum(**kwargs.values())
```

double * unpacked dictionary values, and one * is to unpacked anything(except dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

The number and type of arguments are determined by code of function **init**
In your case this a single argument of type dictionary. So you have always to pass such function f(x) where x is a dictionary.
So the that is function f that deals with the argument.
E.g.

```
def fsum(x): return sum(x.values())
...
__init__(fsum, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
```